# Can a rectangle be a region?

Tags: complex-analysis

The Cauchy-Goursat Theorem states that if a path $\gamma : [a,b] \to R$ is piecewise smooth and simple closed, where $R$ is a simply connected region, and $f:R \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on $R$, then $\int_{\gamma}{f(z)dz} = 0$.

The note first proves for the case that $\gamma$ traces out a rectangle, which I do not believe to be a region (because the points on the edges cannot be contained by a disc), but which surely can be a subset of a region.

My question is that if the rectangle is not a region then how can we consider the case of $\gamma$ tracing out a rectangle as the theorem specifies $R$ to be a region. Are we considering the restriction of $f$ to a rectangle and is it allowed?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood As far as I know, a region is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and for a set to be open every point needs to be contained by a disc, but the points on the edges are certainly not covered by a disc.

Answer (score 0):

The image of $\gamma$ is a rectangle contained in the region $R$. What's the problem? Do you think that the image of $\gamma$ must be the whole region?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, in order to prove the theorem, I do not think one could use a subset which itself is not a region.

Comment: @James If $\gamma$ is a continuously differentiable path, its image is *never* a whole region.

Comment: Okay, then I guess the term region is included for the sake of generalisation due to the function being analytic. Much appreciated for your insightful advice, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @James Please explain why you think that, in order to prove the theorem, the image of $\gamma$ must be the whole region.

Comment: Oh, I thought since the region $R$ is the domain of $f$, every point in $R$ needed to be considered in order to evaluate the integral.